# How to structure Asp.Net MVC pages when returning results

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to you structure ASP.Net MVC pages when you want to display results after the user clicks search?

I have a view called Index.cshtml.  I have partial view called Filter.cshtml that has filter values and a Search button.  When I click the Search button I want to show the results next to the filter criteria. What happens is my partial view Results.cshtml shows on the entire page. What is the correct page structure for this type of scenario, to show my filter values and my results at the same time.

Index.cshml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@{ Html.RenderPartial("Filter"); }
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Results"); }
```

Results.cshtml

```
<div>This will be the results page that should be displayed next to the filter values</div>
```

Controler Action method:

```
  public PartialViewResult Search(HarvestFilter filter)
    {
        return PartialView("Results");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that extra `<div />` markup.  Your call to `@Html.RenderPartial()` will give you the necessary DOM elements for the resulting data.

Just remember that if you're rendering a partial view, you'll have to have your Action Method match the name that you're calling (or use attributes to reflect otherwise).  In other words, you have an Action method called `Search()`, but you have partials getting rendered that don't appear to be your `Search()` Action method.